# 特別ツールバー内の並び順を変更したい

Tags: emeditor

特別ツールバー内のそれぞれのアイコンの並び順を変更するにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

例えば「検索」では赤丸で囲んだ「正規表現を使用する」のボタンを一番左（＝検索窓のすぐ右）に持っていきたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

特別ツール バーの場合には、ボタンの並べ替えは、残念ながら、できないです。